# Python Mako check loop iteration in IF

Tags: python, mako

it seems so simple yet I can't seem to check if the inner loop is at the 7th iteration

```
    % for elem in x:
       ....some stuff
    % for item in y:
      # inner loop    
        % if ${loop.index}==7:
            yAYAYAYAYYAYA
        % endif
        ... 
    % endfor
% endfor
```

I've tried slight variations and wrapping the index in a variable,but all that give me

```
mako.exceptions.SyntaxException: (SyntaxError) invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1) (u'if ${loop.index}==7:pass')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if loop.index == 7:` `${...}` syntax is used for resolving the value as html

Comment: thank you I just started using Mako an hour ago, good to know this!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
%for idx, item in enumerate(y):
    %if idx==7:
        foo
    %endif
%endfor
```